# On page load change span text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the text of a span that does not have an ID, but has a parent ID that I can hook to. My issue is it also has a strong tag that I want undisturbed. I want to change (over 50ft) to (over 75ft) on page load.

```html
<p class="form-row installment-fee form-row-wide" id="distance_fee_field" data-priority=""><label class="checkbox ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox " name="distance_fee" id="distance_fee" value="1"> 
        <span class="added-checks">Extra-long driveway (over 50ft) <strong>+ $5.00/month</strong></span>
        </label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an "static" function, which just replaces the 50ft to 75ft, than the following code should fix your problem.

```
window.onload = function() {
  
  let span = document.querySelector('#distance_fee_field span.added-checks');
  
  span.textContent = span.textContent.replace('50ft', '75ft');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the point here, but this is how you can do:

```
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");
[...spans].forEach(span => {
  let p = span.closest("p");
  if(p.getAttribute("id")) {
    span.innerText = span.innerText.replace("50ft", "75ft");
  }
})
```